# Insert div on next line when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make something similar to what you find in google images. When a picture is clicked, a div with the image appears on the next line over the other images that is under the clicked one.

I have a set of divs with float:left and position:relative. They have different widths. When i click on a div i want a new full width div to appear on the next line. The divs under the clicked one should be bushed down under the full width one.

I tried to do this by looping through the divs and compare the position of the divs to the clicked one like this:

```
    $(".Wrapper").on("click", ".testDivs", function () {
        var thisTop = $(this).position().top;
        $(".testDivs").each(function(i, obj) {
            var otherTop = $(obj).position().top;
            if(thisTop < otherTop){
                $(".fullWidthDiv").insertBefore(obj);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

This doesn't work and I don't really know how I should do this. Any tips/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a solution based on my initial code. This doesn't require all the CSS the other solution that was postet suggested. Adding rows dynamically was also suggested, but this became very complicated when making it responsive to window resizing. Feel free to reply if you have any comments on this

```
 function positionDiv() {
    var checker = false;    
    var n;                
    var thisTop = clickedElement.position().top;   

    $(".testDivs").each(function(i, obj) {
        var otherTop = $(obj).position().top;  

        if(thisTop < otherTop){
            $(".testDivs:eq(" + (i-1) + ")").after($(".fullWidthDiv")); 
            checker = true;
            return false;        
        }
        n = i;                   
    });

    if (!checker) {
        $(".testDivs:eq(" + n + ")").after($(".fullWidthDiv"));
    }
}


var clickChecker = null;
$(".wrapper").on("click", ".testDivs", function () {
    if (clickChecker === this){
        $(".fullWidthDiv").hide();
        clickChecker = null;
    } else {
        $(".fullWidthDiv").show();
        clickChecker = this;
    }

    clickedElement = $(this);

    positionDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    if( clickedElement != null) {
        $(".tagTextWrapper").hide();
        positionDiv();
        $(".tagTextWrapper").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This requires a lot of information to explain. So I'd rather suggest  reading a blog post on this topic.Hope this will help you.

https://www.sitepoint.com/recreating-google-images-search-layout-css/

Comment: Thanks this is perfect :) Making this as the solution if no more clever answers appear

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve that. It will not keep scroll position but that would be another easy fix.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row1 row">
    <div class="img1 img"></div>
    <div class="img2 img"></div>
    <div class="img3 img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2 row">
    <div class="img1 img"></div>
    <div class="img2 img"></div>
    <div class="img3 img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3 row">
    <div class="img1 img"></div>
    <div class="img2 img"></div>
    <div class="img3 img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only applied some styling ti increase visibility of the changes.

```
.img {
  width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid green
}

.big-img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

And finally the JS:

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    var expandedImg = '<div class="big-img"></div>';
  $('.big-img').remove();
    $(this).parent().append(expandedImg);
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5fm2dup/

Comment: The divs are added dynamically and have no parent div for each row so this does not work for me :/

Comment: Hm, you can add them dynamically in rows if you want to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do

```
$(".Wrapper").on("click", ".testDivs", function () {
     $(this).after($(".fullWidthDiv"));
 });
```